# Netsuite how to remove "New" or Add Button from custom list lookups?

Tags: netsuite

I just want a mandatory selection list.I do not want a user of that form to be able to add a new custom list record.

How is this done?

Comment: I tried view only, but then they couldn't select from the list. Maybe I need a user event script to remove it?

Answer (score 3):

The fastest/easiest approach would be is to let your user not use the Administrator role, but instead use a role wherein lists and/or that Custom Record of yours is set to view only.

Comment: Where does one find the view only option?

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit the list and remove he -new- from the list which have the id -1